# Method Not Allowed (POST) I'm stuck

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to fix this for hours. I can't seem to see what's causing the error :(

views.py

```
@login_required
def create_brand(request):
    template_name = "poc/brand_add.html"
    context = {}
    context["form"] = forms.BrandForm()
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = forms.BrandForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            form.save()
            return render(request, template_name, context=context)

    else:
        return render(request, template_name, context=context)
```

forms.py

```
class BrandForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Brand
        fields = ('brand_id' , 'brand_name', 'company')
```

models.py

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', models.DO_NOTHING)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'brand'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.brand_name}"
```

template: brand_add.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

<body>
    {% block content %}
    <div class="container">

        <h1>Create new Brand</h1>
        <form action="{% url 'poc:list_brand' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}

            <input type="submit" value="Create">
        </form>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}

</body>
```

urls.py

```
    path('brand/', views.BrandListView.as_view(), name='list_brand'),
    path('brand_add/', views.create_brand, name='create_brand'),
    path('brand/<int:pk>', views.BrandDetailView.as_view(), name='detail_brand'),
```

Still can't add a 'brand'
Is it because of using function based views instead of CBV?

Comment: I think your form should have the action of `create_brand`, not `list_brand`.

Comment: what error you are getting ? in `create_brand` you need to handle case where `form.is_valid` is  false. you haven't handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are submitting the form to the list view address: `action="{% url 'poc:list_brand' %}"` and the list view may not receive a POST request!

If you are willing to redirect to the list view, you should do the redirection, inside the view code, by returning a `RedirectResponse`.

Comment: as to what @JohnGordon, both of you are correct. thanks, coffee is no longer effective